# How to use "value" as a column name in MySql?

Tags: mysql

How can I use `value` in a select statement in MySql? It is reserved keyword.

Code:

```
SELECT unit.cleunit
 FROM    (   (   metas metas
           INNER JOIN
              metas_unit metas_unit
           ON (metas.clemetaunit = metas_unit.clemetaunit))
       INNER JOIN
          metas_values metas_values
       ON (metas_values.clemetaunit = metas.clemetaunit)
      AND (metas_unit.clemetaunit_values =
              metas_values.clemetaunit_values))
   INNER JOIN
      unit unit
   ON (unit.cleunit = metas_unit.cleunit)
```

WHERE (unit.etatunit <> 0)
   AND (unit.isdeleteunit = 0)
   AND ((metas_unit.`value` LIKE '%%NOM%%')
    OR (metas_values.metavalues_name LIKE '%%NOM%%'))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE `Value` = 1
```

For more info information see [reserved](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) words and [identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html).

Update: the sql query:

```
SELECT unit.cleunit
FROM metas
INNER JOIN metas_unit 
    ON metas.clemetaunit = metas_unit.clemetaunit
INNER JOIN metas_values 
    ON metas_values.clemetaunit = metas.clemetaunit
    AND metas_unit.clemetaunit_values = metas_values.clemetaunit_values
INNER JOIN unit
    ON unit.cleunit = metas_unit.cleunit
WHERE unit.etatunit <> 0 
    AND unit.isdeleteunit = 0 
    AND (metas_unit.`value` LIKE '%%NOM%%' 
         OR metas_values.metavalues_name LIKE '%%NOM%%')
```

Comment: Hi @BluesRockAddict its not giving any results, i used `value`.But empty ist

Comment: @rajasti277 Well, then you have an empty result-set. That's it. It has *nothing* to do with "value as a column name". (If it wasn't quoted then there would a *syntax error*.)

Comment: @pst there is a result set expected but its not displaying..and i am not getting any syntax error also with and without backticks

Comment: @rajasti277, please update your question with your sql statement, sample dataset and expected result. Then we should be able to help you figure it out.

Comment: @BluesRockAddict i have updated my query please check it out and let me know whats wrong in that

Comment: I've updated my answer with formatted query, what happens if you run it?

Comment: @BluesRockAddict i am getting this exception:
Unknown column 'metas_unit.value' in 'where clause'

Comment: @BluesRockAddict again its not showing any search result with no exception.

Comment: Cool. If you empty resultset isn't what you expect, I'd suggest to try removing INNER JOIN statements one by one from your query until you see some data and then you can figure out what is causing the resultset to be empty. This is definitely outside of scope for your original answer, however.